# "unexpectedly found nil ..." error when performing webView.loadRequest(request)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to create an array of custom UIViewControllers and each of them includes a UIWebView.  In the for-loop, at "loadRequest" I am getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  There is definitely a NSURLRequest with a URL, being passed in.  If i comment out "reportVC.reportWebView.loadRequest(request)" everything runs just fine.

```
func createViewControllers(callback:(controllers:[ReportViewController])->()){
    var urls = [NSURL]()
    getPDFs { (pdfURLs) -> () in
        urls = pdfURLs

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        var reportControllers = [ReportViewController](count: urls.count, repeatedValue: ReportViewController())

        for (index,url) in enumerate(urls){

            var reportVC : ReportViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ReportVC") as ReportViewController
            //reportVC.title = ""
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

            reportVC.reportWebView.loadRequest(request)
            reportControllers[index] = reportVC

            if reportControllers.count == urls.count{
                callback(controllers: reportControllers)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all likelihood `reportWebView` in the `reportVC` instance of `ReportViewController` is unbound (bound to `nil`).  Xcode IB declares IBOutlets as 'implicitly unwrapped optionals' - you are required to give them initial values.  When you don't, the first time you access that property it will cause a runtime exception.

Fix the error by ensuring `reportWebView` is bound to a `UIWebView` - either in your storyboard or your code.

Comment: It is bound to a UIWebView on a story board.  I guess I should note,  that the ReportViewController works just fine alone when segued to (ie.  not trying to create an array of them in a different controller).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm with GoZoner... put a breakpoint on that line and verify what do you have in `reportVC.reportWebView`. maybe when you are seguing you are not trying to load an url, and the WebView  shows a default URL you have set in storyboard.

Comment: You all are right.  Breaking on that line reveals that reportsWebView is nil, but it is linked to a UIWebView in the story board.  Is there something else I can do to ensure that it is not nil?

Comment: Upvote w/ checkmark please.  There can be an issue with linking Swift IBOutlets in Xcode but I can't find a proper link...

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your UIWebView object has been properly initialized before you call loadRequest().  If not, you might want to store the URL in a member object of the class until the viewWillAppear() is executed.

Then, from inside viewWillAppear(), call loadRequest().